# Div container suddenly displaying incorrectly - no change in code, what gives?

Tags: html, css

Just as the title says, the div container here for "Participant First Name" and its search box has suddenly displayed weirdly. No code has been touched/changed etc.

This is what it should look like:
[image]

Suddenly somehow today, this is how it looks like:
[image]

Funny thing is, I ran it in CodePen and the "correct" look is displaying there:

https://codepen.io/AYSCodePen/pen/poeQVzv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div class="mar-bot30">
  <div class="head-l">
    <h2><em>A Y S</em></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="head-r">
    <h2 class="inbl"><em>Plus</em></h2>

    <a class="blueadminbutton" href=".">admin menu</a>
    <a class="dkblueadminbutton mar-right30" href="/">main menu</a>

  </div>

  <br class="clr">

</div>

<hr>

<div class="row text-c">
  <h3>Participant Search</h3>
</div>

<div class="row-third text-l">
  <form method="post">
    <select class="selectform" name="partselect">
      <option value=""> - Participant first name - </option>
      
      <option value="<?php echo $rowd['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowd['FirstName']; ?> <?php echo $rowd['LastName']; ?></option>
     
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="partfind" value="partdrop" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row-third text-c">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="partndisnum" maxlength="9" placeholder=" - NDIS number - " />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="partfind" value="partndis" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row-third text-r">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="partname" placeholder=" - part of name - " />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="partfind" value="partname" />
  </form>
</div>


<div class="row-third text-c mar-top30">
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="partid" placeholder=" - id number - " />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="partfind" value="partid" />
  </form>
</div>  

<hr>
```

Anyone got a clue on why this particular page is suddenly weird? Anyone encounter something bizarre like this?

Comment: It will depend on the length of data in dropdown and the screen width. If you don't want this to happen then set min and max width css for dropdown

Comment: I found some in here: https://coderjony.com/blogs/media-queries-in-css-min-width-and-max-width/ did you mean that? Can you please elaborate? And if so, do you know how much px do I need in order to get it back to the way it should be?

Comment: Yeah the media queries handle the behaviour of css on different screen sizes. How much px? That's all upto you to decide. For example, if you are taking standard large laptop screen then its 1440px given that you need to show 3 in one row with some spacing in between then you can do 1440/3 - (spaces) px. You can also try using %

Answer (score 1):

**To recreate the issue**

```
 <select class="selectform" name="partselect">
          <option value=""> - Participant first name - </option>
          <option value="xyz"> -Some Lengthy text to show up - </option> <!-- added this option -->
```

and in css

```
.selectform{
 width: calc(100% - 70px); 
}
```

where 70px  is the width of the button

Answer (score 0):

```
form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Use this in to your style.